# My neural network always classifies samples as the same class

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, computer-vision

I am trying to build the neural network that recognizes human poses in videos. My dataset consists of 1000 files with human poses (each of them has multiple frames, e.g. torch.Size([256, 51, 45]) = [batch_size, features, num_of_frames]). The problem is that my network doesnt seem to learn (the loss is decreasing only for a few epochs and its quite constant after it). At the end network classifies every sample as class number 2. My assumption here is that networks assumes that it is class 2, because class 2 has the larger distribution in my dataset.

**Edit:** My dataset contains actually npz files that have joint keypoints (x location, y location and probability) and no time dimension. One file is one video and has therefore multiple frames with x,y and probability datapoints.

What did I try:

1. I have built two different models, first one is very simple with only few 1D CNN layers. Since this did not work, I tried another which includes LSTM as well. However both models return almost the same result.

**Model A**

```
class ModelA(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden1 = nn.Conv1d(in_features, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.hidden2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.hidden3 = nn.Conv1d(64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride = 2)
        self.hidden4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.hidden5 = nn.Conv1d(128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride = 2)
        self.hidden6 = nn.ReLU()
        self.hidden7 = nn.Conv1d(256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, stride = 2)
        self.hidden8 = nn.ReLU()
        self.hidden9 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2)
        self.hidden10 = nn.Flatten()
        self.hidden11 = nn.Linear(1024, 100)
        #self.hidden12 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.hidden13 = nn.ReLU()
        self.hidden14 = nn.Linear(100, n_outputs)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden1(x)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x = self.hidden3(x)
        x = self.hidden4(x)
        x = self.hidden5(x)
        x = self.hidden6(x)
        x = self.hidden7(x)
        x = self.hidden8(x)
        x = self.hidden9(x)
        x = self.hidden10(x)
        x = self.hidden11(x)
        x = self.hidden12(x)
        x = self.hidden13(x)
        x = self.hidden13(x)

        return F.softmax(x, dim = 1)
```

**Model B**

```
class Dilated_blocks(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feat, out_feat, stride, dilation):
        super(Dilated_blocks, self).__init__()
        self.dilated_conv = nn.Conv1d(in_feat, out_feat, kernel_size = 3, stride = stride, dilation = dilation, padding = 1)
        self.conv_tranform = nn.Conv1d(out_feat, out_feat, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dilated_conv(x)
        x = self.conv_tranform(x)

        return x

class ModelB(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 51, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3) 
        self.batch1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)

        self.conv_block2 = Dilated_blocks(in_feat = 64,out_feat = 128, stride = 2, dilation = 2)
        self.batch2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)

        self.conv_block3 = Dilated_blocks(in_feat = 128, out_feat = 256, stride = 2, dilation = 2)
        self.batch3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)

        self.lstm_extractor = nn.LSTM(input_size=256, hidden_size=512, num_layers=10,
                                      dropout=0.2, batch_first=True)


        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool1d(2) #average, conv instead stride = 2, kernel = 2
        self.flat = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, n_outputs)




    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.batch1(x)

        #x = self.conv2(x) #your version
        x = self.conv_block2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.batch2(x)

        #x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.conv_block3(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.batch3(x)

        out = x.permute(0, 2, 1)

        out, (ht, ct) = self.lstm_extractor(out)

        out = ht[-1]

        out = self.flat(out)

        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return F.softmax(out, dim = 1)
```

2. Since my dataset it unbalanced, I tried to use classes weights in cross entropy loss. I calculated weights over the whole dataset as distribution percentage and passed this tensor to loss function. This also did not improve the performance. Here the loss and accuracy plots.

Model B without class weights

[Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQSlA.png)

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m50QV.png)

Model B with class weights

[Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTu2m.png)

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNCcS.png)

3. I tried different learning rates and this also did not help.
4. If I use much larger number of epochs the loss is starting to decrease, but this learning is very very slow (loss is constant for larger number of epochs e.g., 50 epochs) and is still big after e.g., 200 epochs.

Actually the main problem is that all of these solutions bring almost no difference, and thats why I am assuming that my mistake is maybe somewhere in the code (and not in the model or dataset).

Here the rest of my code:

```
for ep in range(1, num_epochs + 1):

            running_loss = 0.0
            accuracy = 0.0

            val_running_loss = 0.0
            val_accuracy = 0.0

            for iterat, data in enumerate(train_dataloader):

                #reset gradients of all model parameters to zero
                model.zero_grad()

                #set model in training mode
                model.train()

                #get input data: poses and labels 
                poses = data[0].type(torch.float).permute(0,2,1).to(device) 
                labels = data[1].type(torch.long).to(device) 


                #zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                
                #getting labels in the right format for loss function
                most_frequent_values = torch.mode(labels, dim=1).values 
                #forward
                outputs = model(poses) 

                #loss 
                loss = criterion2(outputs, most_frequent_values)
                running_loss += loss.item()                
                
                #backward
                loss.backward()

                #optmize
                optimizer.step()

                #Accuracy
                acc = torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(outputs, most_frequent_values, task = 'multiclass', num_classes=8)
                accuracy += acc.item()
               


            #Validation
            with torch.no_grad():
                
                val_data = next(iter(val_dataloader))

                #set a model in evaluation mode. 
                model.eval()

                #get validation data
                val_poses = val_data[0].type(torch.float).permute(0,2,1).to(device)
                val_labels = val_data[1].type(torch.long).to(device)

                #labels in proper format
                val_most_frequent_values = torch.mode(val_labels, dim=1).values

                #forward
                val_outputs = model(val_poses)

                #loss
                val_loss = criterion2(val_outputs, val_most_frequent_values)
                val_running_loss += val_loss.item()

                #Accuracy
                val_acc = torchmetrics.functional.accuracy(val_outputs, val_most_frequent_values, task = 'multiclass', num_classes=8)
                val_accuracy += val_acc.item()




            #Training statistics for each epoch
            epoch_loss = running_loss / len (train_dataloader)
            train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
            epoch_acc = accuracy / len (train_dataloader)
            train_acc.append(epoch_acc)

            #Validation statistics for each epoch
            val_epoch_loss = val_running_loss 
            validation_loss.append(val_epoch_loss)
            val_epoch_acc = val_accuracy
            validation_acc.append(val_epoch_acc)
```

Does anyone can give me some tips here?

Edit:

Here my loss function and how I calculate weights:

```
classes_distribution = 1/get_classes_weights(whole_dataset)
criterion2 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = classes_distribution.to(device))
```

```
def get_classes_weights(dataloader):

    all_labels = []
        
    for iterati, data in enumerate(dataloader):
            
        labels = data[1].type(torch.long)
        most_frequent_values = torch.mode(labels, dim=1).values
        all_labels.append(most_frequent_values)        
            
    tensor_to_list = [item for tensor in all_labels for item in tensor.tolist()]
            
    number_of_classes = len(tensor_to_list)

    #Count the occurrences of each class
    classes_counts = {}
    for integer in tensor_to_list:
        classes_counts[integer] = classes_counts.get(integer, 0) + 1

    # Calculate the percentage distribution of each class
    percentage_distribution = {}
    for integer, count in classes_counts.items():
        percentage_distribution[integer] = (count / number_of_classes) 
               

    sorted_dict = {k: percentage_distribution[k] for k in sorted(percentage_distribution)}

    classes_weights = list(sorted_dict.values())

    return torch.tensor(classes_weights)
```

Comment: What is your loss function (I see you call it `criterion2`) and what exactly is the distribution of classes? How do you handle class weights in the loss function? I also don't understand the data format. You say it has no time dimension but has multiple frames, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I added the code for loss and weights to the post. My first model was actually inspired by https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/?fbclid=IwAR1MHOMtIO_qjF-cvZd4tw_bUHcNOVvGhofgMm3QxQc_8cGRScA39J4U7TI

Answer (score 0):

If the training loss is plateauing, but the training accuracy is still bad, then it usually means that your model is not complex enough to handle the problem you are giving it.

Adding more layers or more epochs likely won't solve your problem here. Presumably the videos you are sending into your models are 3 dimensional: two dimensions for each frame, plus the dimension of time. By using `Conv1d` and `MaxPool1d` you are misleading your model by telling it that the input data is 1 dimensional, instead of 3 dimensional. Try using `Conv3d` and `MaxPool3d` to tell your model that the input data is 3 dimensional.

It might also make sense to separate out individual frames and classify each frame as a 2 dimensional image. (`Conv2d` and `MaxPool2d`)

Also, balancing the classes in your training data was a good idea, but double check that you are computing the weights correctly. You said that each weight is a distribution percentage, but each weight should actually be the multiplicative inverse of the distribution percentage, i.e. the classes with fewer elements should have a larger weight, and the classes with more elements should have a smaller weight.

Comment: My dataset contains actually npz files that have (x, y, probability) and no time dimension. One file is one video and has therefore multiple frame with x,y and probability datapoints. Do you think that in this case 1D CNNs are insufficient as well?

Comment: I don't fully understand your data format, but it does seem like you are dealing with multidimensional data, so a 1D CNN is unlikely to give you the accuracy you need.

Comment: I was not clear enough. x and y represent joint keypoints on human body.